# Does Multiple css classes work in Outlook desktop client latest (2019 or Microsoft 365)?

Tags: css, outlook

I observed Outlook desktop client only considers first css class in a list of classes in Email.

If we have class1 and class2 for an element, it considers only class1. and ignores class2.

```
<style> .class1{ color: red } .class2 { border: 1px solid blue } </style>

<p class="class1 class2 "> Only class1 is applied in an email in outlook desktop client </p>
```

Is this the actual case? Or do we have a work around to enable multiple classes?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook only handles the first class listed in the `class` attribute and ignores everything else.

See https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/117